# How do I add a new JRE library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been using Eclipse for about a month now but only for creating Android applications. Now that I'm trying to create a Java application (android game using LibGDX). It seems that my JDK is not working, I can create a perfectly working android project but can't create a new Java project that works properly.!

I can't post a picture but the error says : "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved" and when I look at the project Libraries, the JRE System Library shows an error (unbound).

How do I add a new JDK or fix this problem?

Comment: So what does the PROBLEMS tab say exactly?

Comment: Try re-installing the JDK8 for your computer, and then go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> set it to 1.6; and go to Installed JREs and add the directory of the JDK8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Preferences, then navigate to **Java** > **Installed JREs**. There, use the Add... button to select the JDK from your file system (use the "Standard VM" option). Once you've done that (and used the **OK** button to save, you'll probably want to go back into Preferences, to the **Execution Environments** section, and assign the new JRE you defined as the default for some of the EEs (eg, JavaSE-1.7).

Comment: Do I choose "Standard" or Execution Environment Development". And where do I get the JDK from my file system ?

Comment: Updated the answer to mention the "Standard VM" option. The JDK is wherever you installed it - you *have* installed the JDK already, right?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the JDK, but since I'm on a mac, I don't know where to find the file.

Comment: In that case, try the Search... button instead of Add. JDK locations on OS X are a mess, and they seem to change with every Java update they release :-(

Comment: Once I find the JDK directory, there is the Contents folder, which folder do I choose ?

Comment: Actually, I found the right file, it was the "Home" folder, it worked ! Thanks a lot !